# Как обновлять текст label в pyqt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

У меня есть функция вне класса, которая вызывает функцию класса `UiMainWindow` обновления текста `label` и выдается ошибка. 
Мне нужно, чтобы я мог менять текст `label` вне класса.

Я не могу понять, как обновлять текст `label` в *pyqt* вне класса, после запуска приложения я не могу с ним взаимодействовать.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread


def LiveCheck(ui, status):
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        ui.statusUpgrader(status + str(i))
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)


class UiMainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, streamers_links):
        self.streamers_links = streamers_links

    def statusUpgrader(self, status):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", status))
        self.label.repaint()

    def exit(self):
        raise SystemExit(1)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(362, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 336, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 270, 331, 200))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 470, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        for links in range(len(self.streamers_links)):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            item = self.listWidget.item(links)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", self.streamers_links[links]))
            self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Twitch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))

def uinter(ui, streamers_links):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.statusUpgrader('afa')
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def starter(ui, status):
    LiveCheck(ui, status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    streamers_links = ['https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/r6esportsbr2',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6fr',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6de',
                       'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6es',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6jp',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6tw',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6cntwitch',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6th',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/r6esportsna',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6latam',
                        'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6kr']
    status = 'dadada'
    ui = UiMainWindow(streamers_links)
    p = Process(target=starter, args=(ui, status))
    pa = Process(target=uinter, args=(ui, streamers_links))
    pa.start()
    p.start()
    pa.join()
    p.join()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], т.е. ваш пример будучи скопированным и запущенным - выдаст ошибку, о которой вы пишите.

Comment: вроде исправил, еще вам необходим chromedriver(https://chromedriver.chromium.org) и браузер chrome. И файл streamers.txt с любыми ссылками на twitch каналы (https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6
https://www.twitch.tv/r6esportsbr2
https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6fr
https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6de
https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6es
) Каждая ссылка просто на новой строчке без запятых или иных знаков.

Comment: @S.Nick
я изменил код.  Теперь он работает и выдает туже ошибку, но не надо скачивать chrome, chromedriver и иметь файл с ссылками.

Comment: @S.Nick, у меня есть парсер, мне нужно отображать данные парсера в label, то есть обновлять label, когда парсер получает новые значения. Я пытался понять как это все сделать, но у меня ничего не получается. Мне новый вопрос создать или этот изменить?

Comment: создайте новый вопрос. Приложите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо опишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @S.Nick, я создал новый вопрос

Comment: @S.Nick помогите пожалуйста. Никто не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя взаимодействовать в дополнительном потоке с виджетами.
В *Qt* вы должны использовать **`сигналы и слоты`**.

Вам надо изучить раздел [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

---

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА !!!**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

---

```
import sys
#import os
#import time
#from multiprocessing import Process
#from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QApplication, \
    QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread


class UiMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(362, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 336, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 270, 331, 200))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 470, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Twitch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, status, parent=None):
        super(Thread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.status = status
        self.i = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
#            print(self.i)
            self.updateSignal.emit(f'{self.status}{self.i}')
            self.i += 1
            self.msleep(1000)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, UiMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, streamers_links, status):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.streamers_links = streamers_links
        self.status = status

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        
        self.btnThread = QtWidgets.QPushButton("btnThread", self.centralwidget)
        self.btnThread.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 470, 141, 31))
        self.btnThread.setObjectName("btnThread")
        self.btnThread.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        
        for links in range(len(self.streamers_links)):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            item = self.listWidget.item(links)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", self.streamers_links[links]))
            self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
            
        self.statusUpgrader(status)

    def statusUpgrader(self, status):
        self.label.setText(status)

    def exit(self):
        raise SystemExit(1)

    def start_thread(self):
        self.btnThread.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.thread = Thread(self.status)
        self.thread.updateSignal.connect(self.statusUpgrader)
        self.thread.start()
    

streamers_links = [
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/r6esportsbr2',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6fr',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6de',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6es',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6jp',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6tw',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6cntwitch',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6th',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/r6esportsna',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6latam',
    'https://www.twitch.tv/rainbow6kr'
]

status = 'dadada'    
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(streamers_links, status)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]